# Assemble a struct from Bytes received through serial port in C#

Tags: c#, c, struct, port

In C I simply do a memcpy from my data buffer array to the address of my struct.
I am not sure how to do this in C# for the desktop side of things. This is my struct in C#

```
 struct frame_type
    {
        public UInt32 start_of_frame;
        public UInt32 frame_id;
        public UInt16 frame_len;
        public UInt32 crc;
        public UInt32 end_of_frame;

    }
```

And I have a Datareceived serial port callback, the dataIn variable below is a string but obviously  I can change it something else to make it easier to grab all those bytes and assemble the frame.

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        dataIN = port.ReadExisting();

        //increment variable and when i have 34 bytes assemble a frame
        //and checkl if it is an ack frame.
        bytes_received_count++;
        if(bytes_received_count == 34)
        {
            //assemble a frame_type frame
        }

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(sendFirmware));
    }
```

So any suggestions are welcome.

**UPDATE:**
I ended up with this code after some research:

```
     private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
            {
                bytes_received[i] = (byte)port.ReadByte();

            }


            assemble_frame_from_port_bytes();
            // this.Invoke(new EventHandler(sendFirmware));
        }
        public void assemble_frame_from_port_bytes()
        {
            frame.start_of_frame = (UInt32)(bytes_received[3] << 24 | bytes_received[2] << 16 | bytes_received[1] << 8 | bytes_received[0] << 0);
            frame.frame_id = (UInt32)(bytes_received[7] << 24 | bytes_received[6] << 16 | bytes_received[5] << 8 | bytes_received[4] << 0);
            frame.frame_len = (UInt16)(bytes_received[9] << 8 | bytes_received[8] << 0);
            int idx = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                payload[i] = bytes_received[idx++];
            }
            frame.crc = (UInt32)(bytes_received[29] << 24 | bytes_received[28] << 16 | bytes_received[27] << 8 | bytes_received[26] << 0);
            frame.end_of_frame = (UInt32)(bytes_received[33] << 24 | bytes_received[32] << 16 | bytes_received[31] << 8 | bytes_received[30] << 0);
        }
```

It gets the job done, is it great? I dont know but it serves its purpose at this stage. C# surely is a great powerful tool but in the hands of a fool it is crippled haha.

Comment: so are you receiving a string or raw bytes? You say you would bit blit it in C suggesting its raw bytes, but you are reading it into a string, note also that your counting is wrong as ReadExisting coudl read 100 bytes or whatever is ready in the buffer

Comment: yes im receiving raw bytes and its going to a string variable for no reason im not reading it or anything just a place holder for now . So when does the program call this data received function? i thought it called it on every byte received.?

Comment: maybe instead of incrementing a variable i could just  do ` dataIN += port.ReadExisting();` and then act when length of dataIN is the right amount, the question still persist how do I move all those raw bytes and assemble a frame. Ultimately I need to check frame ID and CRC32 elements

Comment: I might be being a bit thick, but your struct only seems to be 18 bytes big- where does the 34 come from? Did you mean to use UInt64s instead of 32s or is there something missing?

Comment: oh yeah there is a payload array not in the struct , which it should be. Thats where the missing bytes are coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In C I simply do a memcpy from my data buffer array to the address of my struct.

I suppose the following is something similar, but I'm not in a position to test it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct frame_type
{
    public UInt32 start_of_frame;
    public UInt32 frame_id;
    public UInt16 frame_len;
    public UInt32 crc;
    public UInt32 end_of_frame;
     

    public static implicit operator frame_type(byte[] data) 
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* b = &data[0])
            {
                return *(frame_type*)b;
            }
        }
  
    }    
}
```

It should allow you to just straight assign a byte array of length 18 to the struct

```
frame_type f = aByteArray18Long;
```

Of course, it is the root of all evil and a safe approach would perhaps look like:

```
static public implicit operator frame_type(byte[] b) 
{
    var f = new frame_type();
    f.start_of_frame = (uint)(b[0]<<24 | b[1]<<16 | b[2]<<8 | b[3]);
    f.frame_id =       (uint)(b[4]<<24 | b[5]<<16 | b[6]<<8 | b[7]);
    f.frame_len =    (ushort)(b[8]<<8 | b[9]);
    f.crc =            (uint)(b[10]<<24 | b[11]<<16 | b[12]<<8 | b[13]);
    f.end_of_frame =   (uint)(b[14]<<24 | b[15]<<16 | b[16]<<8 | b[17]);
    return f;
}
```

ps; it's perhaps easiest to get your bytes by something like:

```
var buf = new byte[18];
for(int x = 0; x<18; x++)
    buf[x] = port.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

ok big caveat, I have no serial port so cannot test

```
      MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < port.BytesToRead; i++) {
            if (buffer.Length == 34)
                break;
             // write needs an array even though its only 1
             byte[] bytes = new bytes[1];
             bytes[0] = port.ReadByte();
             buffer.Write(bytes, 0, 1);
        }
    if (buffer.Length == 34){
        // ok we now have the next 34 bytes in buffer
        var frame = new frame_type();
        // rewind to the beginning
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(buffer)) {
            frame.start_of_frame = br.ReadUInt32();
            frame.frame_id = br.ReadUint32();
            .......
        }
        // rewind to be ready for next block
        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      }
    }
```

the core is using BinaryReader this reads serialized elements from a byte stream, ReadUInt32 pulls the next 4 bytes and marshalls to a UIn32 etc.

The fiddly bit is getting the bytes from thr port into a stream since we cant connect a stream directly to the port (I coulsnt see how to do it) so I use a MemoryStream which, as the name suggests , is a byte stream in memory